# cocoapods on expo project

Tags: firebase, react-native, macos, expo

I have a error this error `Something went wrong running 'pod install' in the 'ios' directory. Command 'pod install' failed. └─ Cause: Error installing boost`  when i run `npx expo prebuild` in my react-native (with expo) project.
I tried to install `cocoapods` with `gem install cocoapods` but still the same error. can't install boost too.

eas.json file:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.3"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

ps: I have a mac pro M2